# Subtracting work days not working

Tags: calculated-column-formula

I tried a formula for subtracting 3 working day, I found googling and a piece of it does not work for me. I found this: `=IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-3),2)=6,DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-4),IF(WEEKDAY(DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-3),2)=7,DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-5),DATE(YEAR(RStartDate),MONTH(RStartDate),DAY(RStartDate)-3)))`

I modified it to have my date field name and it calculates but when I do a date for a Monday, Tuesday or Sunday it calculates whole days and not working days as the formula states it would. I am a newbie to Sharepoint formulas. I looked for a long time on how to interpret the weekday function and have become lost and flustered.

I validated this with Excel networkdays comparison.
Example: Monday 11/6/2017 networkdays is 11/1/2017 but with this formula it is 11/3/2017.

```
sharepoint   EXCEL      start date   weekday
11/3/2017   11/1/2017   11/6/2017   MONDAY
11/28/2017  11/28/2017  12/1/2017   FRIDAY
10/13/2017  10/13/2017  10/18/2017  WEDNESDAY
9/18/2017   9/18/2017   9/21/2017   THURSDAY
9/29/2017   9/28/2017   10/3/2017   Tuesday
9/14/2017   9/13/2017   9/17/2017   Sunday
9/6/2017    9/6/2017    9/9/2017    Saturday
```

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening? Much appreciated :)
Breanna